# Is it mandatory to convert to Swift 4? should I convert even if it's not mandatory?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4

Is it mandatory to convert to Swift 4? should I convert even if it's not mandatory ?

I couldn't find anywhere if it's optional or mandatory,  or if it will be deprecated at some point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It it not mandatory to convert to Swift 4... yet. If you read the [release notes](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10_GM_seed/Release_Notes_for_Xcode_10_GM_seed.pdf) for the upcoming release of Xcode 10 you will see that Xcode 10 will be the last release to support Swift 3. Xcode release cadence runs about one major release per year so a good estimate for the deprecation of Swift 3 is September 2019. The difficulty of migrating from Swift 3 to Swift 4 is commonly reported on industry blogs as being less difficult than previous releases such as moving from Swift 2 to Swift 3.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very good practice to update your project to the latest swift release , e.x now only builds with xcode 9 is only to appstore upload , so if there is a swift 2/3 project it should update , yes you can workaround for swift 3 , but it's too late for swift 2 , same will happen with swift 4 , so keep going on as it's also exciting to know and implement the new syntax / ongoing optimizations , BTW we are very close to **Swift 5**

Comment: Very close meaning the next June?

Comment: @Cristik what makes iphone xs not in June  may do it before the next WWDC , While this https://forums.swift.org/t/is-5-0-release-date-really-2019/13156/2 expects 2019 because of **ABI stability**

Answer (score 1):

All answers are accurate, and very good. For me the bottom line? Two things, one part of your question, one not.

(1) Depricated? ABSOLUTELY. Today this question mean you are either talking Swift 3 or earlier, or Xcode 9 or earlier. Plan for it. Since you give no details about YOUR situation, I'll add that we don't see this sort of "annual versioning and deprecating" with Obj-C. But remember, the entire language *seems* to be deprecated anymore.

(2) Don't "code" for the past. You tagged the question iOS, so you probably know what's been added and/or deprecated over the years....

Added... AutoLayout. Size classes. Collection views. Screen sizes. iPad multi-tasking.

Depricated... Swift 1. Swift 2. Swift 3 and OpenGL (soon).

If you are programming for iOS *and/or* using Swift, the price you *must* pay is annual maintenance for something like deprication. Without any ore details - admit it, your question is extremely light on details - one has to say (today Xcode 10 became GM including Swift 4.2 which is not even available on Xcode 9) that emphatically **YES**, even though it's not "mandatory", one is committing themselves to a harder road to things if they are using iOS, Swift, and *not* using Swift 4.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't update you will end up left behind.

- Xcode 8 dropped support for Swift 1
- Xcode 9 dropped support for Swift 2
- Likely some Xcode 10.x will probably drop support for Swift 3
- And Xcode 11.x will drop support for Swift 4

If you don't upgrade, at some point you'll be unable to submit apps to the store, and you'll need to keep old versions of Xcode around to do any automatic conversions.

Save yourself the long term pain, and just keep up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is not mandatory but highly recommend.
You didn’t mention in your question in which version is currently your source code, and based on XCODE previous history and evolution, the migration between swift version is handled by XCODE quite well for the recent version, so if your code is currently in swift 3, you should hurry up if you want a smooth migration.
In general, I would say is best practice to keep your code as updated as possible to enjoy the new features and be able to plan for the future, XCODE 10 also compiles faster  code written in swift 4.2.
keeping in mind  few rules:

- Always should do the migration in a private branch
- Check the results, run few sanity test and all your unit test before adopting the new version,

In that way  minimizing the risks considerably.

**Bottom line:** is not a must but you should do it